# C# - Decimal to integer and round depending on value

Tags: c#, integer, double

I'm trying convert a `decimal` into `integer` and want to round the value up or down depending on the situation.

Basically example is:

- 12/3 = 4 so should round to 4
- 11/3 = 3.66666 so should round to 4
- 10/3 = 3 = 3.33333 so should round to 3
- 9/3 = 3 so should round to 3

Whatever I found on the internet always rounds down or always rounds up, never makes a judgment call based on the numbers.

Comment: find the first number after the decimal and add one if it's higher than 4

Comment: I don't understand... the Math.Round() method always round to the nearest...

Comment: I agree with Bartdude: I think you've misread the docs for `Math.Round`.

Comment: @Bartdude: Absolutely, I don't see the problem, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `x` is the number you want to round and you want the "normal" rounding behavior (so that .5 always gets rounded up), you need to use `Math.Round(x, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`. Note that if you are actually computing fractions and the numerator and denominator are integers, you need to cast one of them to double first (otherwise, the division operator will produce an integer that is rounded down), and that if you want the result to be an `int`, you need to cast the result of `Round()`:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
double answer = (int) Math.Round(a / (double) b, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: well here is an interesting discovery, at least for me.

When I run this code

Double number1 = 11/3;
    int roundedNumber = (int)Math.Round(number1);
    Label1.Text = roundedNumber.ToString();
Result is 3

When I run this code

Double number1 = 10.66666;
    int roundedNumber = (int)Math.Round(number1);
    Label1.Text = roundedNumber.ToString();
Result is 4

It goes to prove what you are saying.  I guess my problem was that I always ran the first scenario when tested examples from the internet.

Comment: @Bagzli In .NET 11/3 would result in integer division, which will abandon the decimal place, which would appear like it always rounds down. When doing division, always remember to cast variables to a type supporting decimal places (float, double, decimal) or use the correct format for literals (1f = float, 1d = double, 1m = decimal)

Comment: Yeah, I get that now.  I thought that by casting it into a double it would give a double answer no matter what i gave it to divide.  What I didn't realize was that left side and right side of the equal sign are 2 separate operations independent of each other.  I guess we learn something new every day.  Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Does [Math.Round(d)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx) do what you require?

Return Value:
The integer nearest parameter d. If the fractional component of d is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, the even number is returned. Note that this method returns a Decimal instead of an integral type.

Check out the [Round reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx)

Comment: Probably not entirely, due to the unusual default midpoint rounding behavior - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Round(value)` should do what you want. Examples console app code to demonstrate:

```
Console.Write("12 / 3 = ");
Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(12d / 3d));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.Write("11 / 3 = ");
Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(11d / 3d));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.Write("10 / 3 = ");
Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(10d / 3d));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.Write("9 / 3 = ");
Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(9d / 3d));
Console.WriteLine();

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
Math.Round(d, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Sometime, people add 0.5 to the number before converting to int.